# Can an SSIS script component send more than 25,000 rows at a time?

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012

We have several SSIS packages that sync records from Microsoft AX to our warehouse management system, we use a script component in it that calls a query service within AX to get the records and then we insert them into our target table in SSMS. On a single run it will grab 25000 exactly and send those over, is there a way to increase how many it will send over in a single run? We didn't set this 25000 limit it's just something we've always seen happen with any of them that are trying to send more than that.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/sql-server-2016-ssis-data-flow-buffer-auto-sizing-capability/ba-p/305271

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I've been trying to find. I don't understand something here, we have the same defaults this mentions with DefaultBufferMaxRows = 10000, how are we sending through 25000 each run?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no row limitation within SSIS itself. Here we have 25,001 rows flowing through a data flow.

[image]

Is there a default limit to Dynamics AX queries of 25,000? Yes there is

> From a single call to the query service, the default maximum number of rows that can be returned from a query data source is 25,000. This means that each data table in the dataset returned by the query service can have up to 25,000 records if you do not specify a record limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/handling-large-datasets-returned-by-the-query-service